# bash remove files less than string value

Tags: bash, cron

A cron action saves database files on an hourly basis and assigns a file name based on year, month, day and hour

```
/$(date +\%m)/$(date +\%y\%m\%d\%H)_thedb.sql
```

This leads to archive bloat and the goal is to keep the last file of the day (i.e. delete all those lesser than `15050923*` ) in a separate cron action.

What is an effective way of achieving this?

Comment: If you say `ls -1rt`, the last file in the list will be the newest. Store it and remove the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start with complex bash string substitutions, I suggest you try to go after the file date. `find` can help you with that.

For example, to delete all files in a directory that are older than 5 days, you could try something like this:

```
find <DIR> -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

Now if there are subdirectories in `<DIR>`, you might also want to include the options `-type f` to limit the finding to files, and `-maxdepth 1` to not search subdirectories.

If you have a file and want to delete everything older than that, you could slightly modify this:

```
find <DIR> -not -newer <FILE> -not -name <FILE> -exec rm {} \;
```

I simply don't know why there is no `-older` search term in `find`, it seems so obvious.

**Warning:** I strongly recommend to first leave out `-exec` and everything after it to check whether the files it finds can all be deleted.

Comment: Interesting, however given the differences a day_of_the_week and calendar date can generate, which is another practical concern, this approach would create more work.